# How can one define a type hint for dict keys having invalid variable names in python?

Tags: python-3.x, types, python-typing

If I have a key in a dictionary that is always required, where the key name is not a valid python variable name, like Content-Type, how do I define the type hint for that dict and the key?

The below does not work:

```
import typing

class Headers(typing.TypedDict):
    Content-Type: str
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an alternate syntax for typing.TypedDict that you can use which uses string keys.
It is shown in the docs here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html?highlight=typeddict#typing.TypedDict

Here's how you can make a class with that type hint and instantiate it

```
Headers = typing.TypedDict('Headers', {'Content-Type': str})
headers = Headers({'Content-Type': 'blah'})
```